# Connection PHP to Paradox database

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, paradox

I need to make a connection with PHP to a database created with Paradox (about the year 2004, I think). It is a very old database and there is no way to find information online.

I have tried with xampp, wamp but they do not bring by default any library that can read that type of database from PHP. I have read on the internet that xampp (for example) stopped giving support to Paradox on the year 2008. I imagine that wamp the same.

So, does anyone have any experience with this type of database? I would appreciate any kind of guidance on this subject.

Comment: I found something in the [PHP-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.paradox.php)

Answer (score 1):

I answer to myself in case someone else has to work PHP (4, 5.x, 7...) with the Paradox database and they have this problem too.

The first is to create a connection odbc with the tool: "ODBC data source". This program comes installed in windows by default.

In the tab: "System DSN", optcion "Add".

Search for the connection "Microsoft Paradox Driver (* .db)", accept it. Add a name and select the directory where we have our database.

Finally, edit the php.ini file and add (or uncomment) these lines:

```
extension = php_odbc.dll
extension = pdo_odbc
```

With this we will be able to work with paradox databases in any version of PHP.