# How to use ODBC to connect with Paradox DB with PHP?

Tags: php, odbc, connection-string, paradox

I'm currently working on a project: Write a Web Application that is able to make connection to **pdx .db** file.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260057/connection-php-to-paradox-database) gave me a little hint, but it was not complete. What I got from it is basically to use **ODBC** to work with **Paradox** databases.

But since resources about **Paradox DB** is very limited, I have not found any manual about how to connect to **Paradox** with **Php & ODBC**.

What I have tried:

```
<?php
   $database = "C:/Data/data.db";
   $conn = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )};Database=".$database, '', '');
?>
```

But then it returned this message:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

If anyone knows how to fix the connection string, please kindly help.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `echo (8 * PHP_INT_SIZE) . "-bit<br/>";` display?

Comment: It displays 64-bit, so that means PHP version is x64?

Comment: Yes, and that explains the error message because Jet-based ODBC drivers (of which the Paradox driver is one) are only available to 32-bit applications.